# Jquery - Dynamically build form action on submit?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have the action of a HTML form built when the user clicks the submit button.

So the user fills in a form, clicks submit, then the action gets built *then* it actually gets submitted. The reason being is because the form has a load of options on it which will be passed to a script.

How would I go about doing this with Jquery?

Comment: I'll caution you to think about what happens when your user has JS disabled.  The form would still get submitted, but without the form's action getting changed.  Does this break your server-side script?

Comment: Hi, normally I would not rely on JS for core functionality, but this is just for an in house tool I'm building so it's not so much of a problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Untested, but this should at least get you on your way:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (event)
{
    var action = '';
    // compute action here...
    $(this).attr('action', action);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yourFormId').submit(function() {
    $(this).attr('action', 'dynamicallyBuildAction'); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The plain Javascript solution would have a function:

```
function changeAction() {
  this.action = 'the dynamic action';
  return true;
}
```

In the form you would set the onsubmit event:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return changeAction();">
```

To do the same using jQuery would be:

```
$(function(){
  $('IdOfTheForm').submit(function(){
    this.action = 'the dynamic action';
    return true;
  });
});
```