# Rewrite $_GET to/$1/$2

Tags: mod-rewrite, get, hyperlink, nice

I have next form:

```
<form action="/" method="get"  name="main">

   <select size="1" name="type" id="sel" class="dropdown">
        <option value="Class1"  >YES</option>
        <option value="Class2"  >NO</option>
        </select>

    <input type="text" name="text"/>

      <button id="go" type="submit"/>Get the Results!</button>
</form>
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_^/]+)/$ /index.php?type=$1&text=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_^/]+)/?$ /index.php?type=$1&text=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The question is: How i can send users to http://site.com/class1/text/ so the **.htaccess** code work?

Now form send them to **/?type=class1&text=sometext**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following *before* the first RewriteCond in your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=(\w+)&text=(\w+)
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2/? [QSD,R]
```

In theory this should redirect `/?type=class1&text=sometext` to `/class1/sometext/`.  This will then be matched by the following RewriteRules, which should call the index.php with the correct parameters, but not change the URL in the browser.

Also, you probably only need the second of your RewriteRules, as the `/?` will match there being a slash, and there not being one.

Comment: Internal Server Error...:( on host.com
With RewriteRule ^.* /%1/%2/? [QSD,R]

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that then - I was only able to test it on [madewithlove](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Just tried remove QSD - (don't see it in apache manual), Chrome said there is too many redirections,
tried to change it on QSA - have error with next output 
/class1/sdd/?&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&type=class1&text=sdd

Comment: QSD deletes the Query String, QSA adds it: [RewriteRule flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd). QSD may not be in your version, and the `?` at the end should have the same effect anyway.

Comment: Removing QSD goes to host.com/class1/text/ but get error with too many redirections...can i go throught this somehow?
Thanks for try to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my question :)
With .htaccess we will have too much rediretions, so to recieve links with type

**http://site.com/class1/text/**

I added a JQuery code to form, so needed link generates at submit:

```
$('#seform').submit(function (event)
{
    var type = $("#sel").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
       var action = '/'+type+'/'+text;
      $(this).attr('action', action);
});
```

**Thanks to** [@Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675580/jquery-dynamically-build-form-action-on-submit)