# PHP Redirect on Submission Based on Different id/URL

Tags: javascript, php, web-deployment

I am looking for a PHP Script that can redirect users to specific and different URLS when they hit "Submit" button.

I can afford to have the URL Like

```
www(.)mydomain(.)com/form.php?id=www(.)rediectedurl(.)com
```

Now if the user clicks submit button it redirects him/her to www.redirecturl.com. So for multiple posts i can easily change the URL and it redirects differently?

I hope anyone can answer it.

Thanks

Comment: First, don't ask for free work. Second, just point the forms action to whatever URL you want.

Comment: java != javascript, and i dont see either one being used here

Comment: First, You are here to help, for free i think? Right?. Second, Not a good idea

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675580/jquery-dynamically-build-form-action-on-submit

Comment: Help, yes. Do all the work for you, no.

Comment: @PatrickEvans PHP or JavaScript doesn't matters. I want it to work. :)

Comment: Why not a good idea?Do you want like, all form processing here then, header("Location: www.redirecturl.com");

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to escape the "URL" types of characters in your domain.com URL so that PHP can properly read the second one as a parameter. So if you wanted to redirect to `www.redirect.com?foo=bar`, your main URL would look something like:

```
www.mydomain.com/form.php?id=www.redirect.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar
```

Now, `form.php` needs to do several things:

- Read the parameter
- Unescape it
- Use PHP's built-in `header()` function to set the "Location" header to the unescaped parameter

  - Example: `header("Location: www.redirect.com?foo=bar");`

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: I want it to be automatic. I don't want to Edit the Header again and again? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Right. That's why you have the first two steps there. You need to read the parameter, unescape it, and *then* use that string with the `header()` call. Something like: `header("Location: $url");`

Comment: And what function, I will be using to call $url as "ww.redirect.com?foo=bar"?

Comment: Use `$_GET` to get the parameters and their values. Then you can use `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to swap between the encoded/unencoded values for that parameter.

Comment: Tried using few. none worked.

Comment: Can you provide me the working code?