# jQuery submit() and form action not working

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a simple search field:

```
  <form id="searchForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="searchField" id="searchField" value="">
  </form>
```

I've tried several variations of this ([related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675580/jquery-dynamically-build-form-action-on-submit)):

```
<script>
  $('#searchField').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {    // hit enter
      $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
          var val = $('#searchField').val();
          this.action = "index.php?g="+genre+"&s="+val; 
          return false;
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

and this:

```
<script>
  $('#searchField').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {    // hit enter
      var val = $('#searchField').val();
      $('#searchForm').attr("action","index.php?g="+genre+"&s="+val);
      $('#searchForm').submit();
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```

But am unable to get the page (action) to direct to the desired page. Even if I try and set the action externally (eg: Google.com), it will not send me there. What am I missing? The genre var is declared previously btw.

Also, I know it needs validation - just trying to get it working first.

Thanks

Comment: what is `genre` & is there any error in your browser console

Comment: the first variant is wrong... but the second one has to work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YtCL3/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny genre is just a one word string. No errors.

Comment: are you sure that the keypress handler is getting called

Comment: i think `genre` is undefined

Comment: if I put an alert(genre) before the attr line, it reveals a text string so it is defined @AwladLiton

Comment: Second example returns (path)...index.php?searchField=asdfasdfasdf (where that is the value I typed in)

Comment: @RonitAdhikari Added a submit button, same result as comment above

Comment: inside if try putting e.preventDefault(); this will work

Comment: Even if I manually put the parameter values into the action url string it breaks. Seems to work on pure urls however.

Comment: @RonitAdhikari added `e.preventDefault();` (after `submit()`), didn't make a difference

Comment: @john no no i am telling just after if (e.which == 13) { e.preventDefault();//and rest of code goes }

Comment: Your answer with that directly after the `e.which` returns `.../index.php?searchField=asfasdf` still (where that is what I put in the field) @RonitAdhikari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="searchForm" action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searchField" value="">
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#searchField').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {   
        var genre = 'test';
        var val = $('#searchField').val();
        $('#searchForm').attr("action","index.php?g="+genre+"&s="+val);
        $('#searchForm').submit();
          return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Try Now... I have changed the form method to post now its working fine.

Comment: Same result, takes me to  (path)...index.php?searchField=asdfasdfasdf (where that is the value I typed in)

Comment: And one more you will have to define 'gerne' for now i have defined statically below 'if condition'.

Comment: Even if I remove genre (and val) and replace it with a string(s) in the url itself (so that action is one string), it doesn't work. seems to be an issue with urls containing params not working altogether.

Comment: It was the missing `method="post"` that made the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the second approach. But you have to provide your script inside Jquery's document.ready function.

```
<script>    

$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#searchField').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {    // hit enter
        var genre = 'abcd';
            var val = $('#searchField').val();
            $('#searchForm').attr("action","index.php?g="+genre+"&s="+val);
            $('#searchForm').submit();
            return false;
        }
    });

});

</script>
```