# Dynamic form action pointing to Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom

I've been trying to create a HTML form in my nodejs app, which directs to the appropriate express route when submitted. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675580/jquery-dynamically-build-form-action-on-submit), I've gotten to the solution below:

```
<script>
$('#controlPanel').submit(function(event) {
  var view = document.getElementsByName('selectView').value;
  var date = document.getElementsByName('selectDate')
    .value
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 10);
  var action = "/".concat(view).concat("/").concat(date);
  $(this).attr('action', action);
});
</script>
```

However, the problem is, the resulting action string is wrong no matter what methods and functions I put the component elements through.

Instead of something like "http://example.page/month/2018-01-01"
I get something like "http://example.page/?selectView=month&selectDate=2018-01-01"

What could I do to ensure the dynamic action conforms to the former example?

EDIT: The HTML used (also appended surrounding script html tags to code above):

```
<form id="#controlPanel">
  View:<select name="selectView">
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="week">Week</option>
    <option value="day">Day</option>
  </select><br/>
  Date: <input type="date" name="selectDate" min="2007-01-01"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML code as well?

Comment: Edited the HTML to original question.

Comment: you need to add the method attribute on the form element, try `method="post"`, you also need to stop the default submission with `preventDefault()`, and then once you modify the action submit it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a few things trying to solve this:
For unknown reasons, using attr() didn't work.
Trying to set the method to POST caused an exception (yes, even when I made the changes to the router to have the route use POST).
Using GET still sticks GET parameters with a ? separator at the end, but the route functions as intended despite this.

The solution I ended up with, for others trying to do something similar:

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   document.getElementById("#controlPanel").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var view = document.getElementsByName('selectView')[0].value;
     var date = document.getElementsByName('selectDate')[0].value !== "" ? document.getElementsByName('selectDate')[0].value.slice(0, 10) : "";
     var action = "/".concat(view).concat("/").concat(date);
     document.getElementById("#controlPanel").action = action;
     document.getElementById("#controlPanel").submit();
   });
 });
</script>
```

The only relevant bit of HTML:

```
<form id="#controlPanel" method="get" action="">
```